# Need help taking innerHTML from div with class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take div innerHTML, but I cant give that div ID so I try to take it by classname. Here is that html:

```
<div class=" nicEdit-main    " style="width: 499px; margin: 4px; min-height: 149px; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable="true"><div align="center"><ol><li><sub><font size="5">+++</font></sub></li></ol></div></div>
```

And here is what I've tried to do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(" nicEdit-main ").innerHTML;
```

Bu it returns unidefined. What can i do to take that innerHTML?

Comment: Don't you see that `Elements` is plural? It returns a list of all the elements with that class, not just one. So how can you take the innerHTML of all of them at once?

Comment: Why can you not give your div an ID? Although I have provided an answer to your question, I imagine this is a bigger problem that needs solving.

Comment: Because NicEditor creates this html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array and not a single element (note the `s` in the middle).

IF your element is the only element of that class, then it will be the first element of the array and so `document.getElementsByClassName(" nicEdit-main ")[0].innerHTML` will return what you want.

However, this is very bad practice as classes are meant as a reference to many elements and not one single element. I recommend giving the div a unique ID and selecting it using that instead.

Comment: careful with this function....
getElementsByClassName() not works in any browsers...

Comment: @DZanella - I don't think you are correct. See here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

Comment: But still it's undefined look https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18419/

Comment: No, it isn't - you are not alerting the result correctly. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18420/ (click on the result to see the alert.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("nicEdit-main")[0].innerHTML
```